# Error when opening cmd file from a button

Tags: java

I created a cmd file called message.cmd and I want to open him by a button, his content is:

```
MSG * "this is a message"
```

and I tried to open it by this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start lockComputer.bat");
```

and it shows me an Error:

> 'MSG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

And if open this file from the project folder it works.

In addition I tried to open this code in cmd file by a button and it worked:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll , LockWorkStation
```

What can I do?

Comment: set the full path for the MSG command, ex c:/a/MSG * "Hello Buddy :D"

Comment: :( it's doesn't work. Anyone else?

Comment: the error you are talking means the MSG application not found, you need to either set the full path in the bat file (as I said) or set or add the default path to the MSG root folder

Comment: I tried to write the full path but it is shows me:
'C:\Windows\System32\msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: would you please share your bat file codez?

Comment: This file located at the project folder, his content:
C:\Windows\System32\msg * "hello"
If I open it from the folder it works, but by the program it not.

Comment: Okay, okay, and would you test this too %SystemRoot%/System32/msg * "Hi Dude :D"

Comment: It's not work I sure that the problem not relate to the syntax.
I tried to lockdown my computer, and it successed, why when I use path or any command (like ipconfig) it doesn't work?!

Comment: try to use other like %SystemRoot%\System32\ping, or %SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig, have a try, do same with MSG

Comment: Not works, I think the program search for msg.exe file in his folder... (netBeans project -> xxx)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works for me

```
package arash.blogger.example.thread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String sysRoot=System.getenv("WinDir");
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping 127.0.0.1",new String[]{}, new File(sysRoot+"/System32"));
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while( (s=br.readLine())!=null ){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If you can explain to me what is: System.getenv("WinDir");
And why do you enter in the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() many values?

Comment: System.getenv() is used for returning OS global variable, where in Win machines, WinDir variable refers to the location OS installed (like C:/Winnt50 or d:/windows), so because ping, ipconfig,... are located under WinDir/System32, you need to specify the folder you want to run the ping process (if you don't then system search for ping in application path that doesn't exist), could you solve the problem?